# Auto Compile Less in JAVA for different customer Less files

Tags: java, spring, maven, less

Our client has a product (JAVA Implemented) that is used by different customers with different color schemes. We are using less for this and WinLess tool. In our CSS folder we have the following less files :

```
customer1.less
customer2.less 
customer3.less
style.less
```

`customer*.less` file contains Less color variables.  `style.less` imports at top one of these `customer*.less` file

Now every time the client wants to release a new version of the app to a specific customer, he needs to change the `@import` filename to specific `customer*.less` filename. Doing this filename change causes WinLess to compile and create/update `style.css` which is linked in the `<head>` of the pages.

Is there any way to do this automatically during the `build time or during tomcat server start`? I did some research on Java LESS compilers and some stackoverflow posts over here, but didn't find any straight forward answer - specially the part where we `@import` another `customer*.less` file in main `style.less`.

FYI: 
We have the different testing configurations set for different customers in `JAVA_OPTS` variable. Also in `application-context.xml` we have the `${customer_configuration_name}` that comes from individual `customer*.properties` file.

Considering I am not a JAVA proficient ( actually i am a Javascript developer ) and one who does not understand JAVA world like Maven, Spring etc, What would be the best way to implement a solution to this problem or propose an approach to client?

Answer (score 0):

Finally after a bit of research and tryout, i got a solution using `ServletContextListener` and [lesscss-java](https://github.com/marceloverdijk/lesscss-java). Here is what worked :

### web.xml:

Add below line so that tomcat can call this class on server startup

```
<listener>
        <listener-class>my.app.listener.LessServletContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

### LessServletContextListener.java

```
package my.app.listener;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;

import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;

import org.lesscss.LessCompiler;

public class LessServletContextListener implements ServletContextListener{

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
        System.out.println("LessServletContextListener Destroyed");
    }

    // Run this before web application is started
    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {

        String cssDir = getCSSDirectory();      
        String styleLessPath = cssDir + File.separator + "styles.less";
        String styleCssPath = cssDir + File.separator + "styles.css";

        String vendorLessFilename = getVendorLessFilename();        
        replaceLessAndCompile(styleLessPath, styleCssPath, vendorLessFilename);
    }

    public void replaceLessAndCompile(String filePath, String cssPath, String lessFilename) {
        try {
            String replaceText = "@import \"" + lessFilename + "\";";

            FileReader fr = new FileReader( filePath );
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            String line; String existing = ""; String input = "";

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                input += line + '\n';

                if(line.startsWith("@import")) {
                    existing = line;
                }
            }

            br.close();

            input = input.replace(existing, replaceText);

            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream( filePath );
            fileOut.write(input.getBytes());
            fileOut.close();

            // Instantiate the LESS compiler
            LessCompiler lessCompiler = new LessCompiler();
            lessCompiler.compile(new File( filePath ), new File( cssPath ));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Problem reading file.");
        }
    }

    private String getCSSDirectory() {
        return System.getProperty("user.dir") + 
            File.separator + 
            ".." + 
            File.separator + 
            "webapps" + 
            File.separator + 
            "css";
    }

    private String getVendorLessFilename() {
        String vendorLessFilename = "default.less";
        String vendor = System.getProperty("MY_VENDOR"); // variable set in JAVA_OPTS of catalina.bat

        if( vendor.equals("CUSTOMER1") ) {
            vendorLessFilename = "customer1.less";
        }else if( vendor.equals("CUSTOMER2") ) {
            vendorLessFilename = "customer2.less";
        }else if( vendor.equals("CUSTOMER3") ) {
            vendorLessFilename = "customer3.less";
        }

        return vendorLessFilename;
    }

}
```

### Whats happening here??

We register `LessServletContextListener`in applications `web.xml`. This way tomcat knows what class to call on startup. Once the server (tomcat) is started, it calls my `LessServletContextListener`, the `contextInitialized` method is automatically called. It gets the CSS directory path where the less files are present. Gets vendor specific less filename based on the vendor name in `JAVA_OPTS`. Next `replaceLessAndCompile` method reads the main `styles.less` file which contains `@import` code. Replaces it with the customer less filename, saves and then [lesscss-java](https://github.com/marceloverdijk/lesscss-java) compiles to `styles.css`. Hope its helps someone! If you found there is much better way to do it, comments are appreciated.